# почему при отправке headers через ngrok на локальный сайт laravel возвращает 405 ошибку?

Tags: php, laravel

Токен все там приходит все ок не отправляется с заголовками когда использовать `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http`

Подключаюсь к локальному сайту через `https://ngrok.com/`

```php
public function test_logout() 
{
    Artisan::call('passport:install');
    $this->post('api/auth/register', [
        'name' => 'userthree',
        'email' => 'userthree@mail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'password'
    ]);
    $res = $this->post('api/auth/login', [
        'email' => 'userthree@mail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'device_name' => 'Iphone 14 PRO MAX'
    ]);
    $dataToken = json_decode($res->getContent())->data;
    $response = Http::withToken($dataToken->token)->post($host . '/api/auth/logout', [
        'token_id' => $dataToken->id
    ]);
    dd($response->status());
}
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что `/api/auth/logout` по методу post у вас объявлен в роутах?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Если это какой-то тест то он не корректный, надо сравнивать фактический результат с ожидаемым, а не просто выполнять какую-то цепочку запросов... по-хорошему, вообще на каждый запрос свой тест

Comment: @InDevX этот тест feature он проверяет глобально маршрут logout а вывод $response->status() просто что знать ошибку.  не работает cUrl когда выполняю Http::withToken($dataToken->token) 
если сделать просто post и отключить auth то работает не рабьотает именно с Http

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar тут все корректно если убратьHttp::withToken($dataToken->token) и отключить auth маршрута тогда работает как только использую Http::withToken($dataToken->token) cUrl не хочет видимо

Comment: @ProgRamm А читали ответ, который присылается? Не статус, а сообщение. Возможно, так станет проще

Comment: @ProgRamm это не feature тест) у вас есть метод, отдельный метод который генерит токен юзеру - юзать его надо... регистрация юзера это 1 тест, логин юзера  - 2 тест, логаут - 3 тест

Comment: Вы откройте через ctrl метод $this->post и увидите что там 3 параметр - headers, вот там их и использовать надо

Comment: @InDevX спасибо это решило) а насчет того что я сразу регистрирую потом авторизируюсь так как писали что тесты выполняются не попорядку поэтому нужно каждый отдельно а так как я делаю RefreshDatabase то мне нужно чтобы данные то были чтобы авторизоваться

Comment: @ProgRamm нет... если надо - создавать юзера, добавлять токен и тп. то это надо делать в каждом тесте (не через запросы на сайт т.к. эти запросы тестить надо, каждый отдельно), при этом, как я уже писал, создавать надо "внутренними" методами, есть у объекта модель - создаём фабрику для модели и в тестах юзаем именно создание с этой фабрикой, в каждом тесте.